# Change Firefox search engine for main search box when new tab is opened

Tags: firefox, search

I'm having trouble getting all my searches not to use yahoo.com as my search engine in Firefox.

After changing settings in Preferences>Search to Google, Firefox still uses Yahoo when I open a new tab and use the main (largest) search box, which is outlined with the large red rectangle below. The smaller search box (marked with a smaller red rectangle) does however use Google. [image].

I'm stuck searching for answers since I'm not sure what to call the large search box versus the smaller search box, and I'm not sure if it is normal that these two are acting differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the selected search engine by doing the following:

1. Type `about:config` in the address bar.
2. Click on the "I'll be careful, I promise" button.
3. Change the following entries:

> - browser.search.selectedEngine = Google
> - keyword.URL = http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=

Comment: Did this, and it didn't work. I then searched "yahoo" once I typed "about:config" and changed a few results to "Google". Now the big red rectangle search box does not work at all... Guess I should have followed through with my "promise" a bit more closely

Comment: You broke it by changing the url entries. Did you change the `keyword.URL` entry? See my updated answer.

Comment: I did a clean reset of all about:config, then changed search engine in preferences - now everything works as expected! Didn't even need to go into about:config. I think I had some atypical thing going before.

Comment: Just noticed that this clean reset also got rid of my extensions. I suspect that one of these extensions was responsible for the unwanted search behavior.

Comment: Good to hear. I had to modify the two entries in my answer to change the "New Tab" search engine. I guess resetting your `about:config` is another way to do it if you don't mind losing any other changes you may have made.

Comment: Are you saying all of your extensions were uninstalled?

Comment: yes they were - although I didn't have many (and I was not signed in) since I am just exploring if I want to change from Chrome to Firefox.

Comment: Ok. In the future if the search engine reverts back to Yahoo, changing the entries in my answer should suffice. Resetting `about:config` would be my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* ways to select a search engine in newer versions of Firefox: from the icon list that shows as soon as you start to search, which is a single-use change, or by selecting *Change Search Settings*, and select *Default Search Engine* from the list -- **this setting stays in place**.

You can also get to that dialog from *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Search*.

Comment: I do not have an options dialog under tools? The other way you mentioned did not work to change the behavior of the search box marked by the big red rectangle in my original question.